# Solving $1-x^2 = \ln x$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, problem-solving

How to solve $1-x^2 = \ln x$ or $x^2 -1 = \ln x$

I know it can simply be checked that 1 is the answer. Even if we say $x = e^{(x^2 -1)}$ it can be easily checked that one is answer but it is not easily solved without checking numbers. or even if we say $1- 2x^2 =\ln x$ then we can't solve this by checking numbers. How this equations can be solved?

Comment: i would say it is $x=1$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Just out of curiosity, do you ever read questions beyond the title? The asker knows this.

Comment: Informal solution : Draw $\ln x$ and $1-x^2$. They intersect at a single point, hence the only solution is $x=1$.

Comment: In general, you need some numerical methods to solve this type of problems.

Comment: yes sorry i have misread this and sorry after a hard day of working

Comment: derivate both sides.

Comment: You can solve $1-ax^2=\ln x$ with the 
[Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambertw). Maple gives
$$x=e^{-\tfrac{1}{2}W(1+2ae^2)}$$

Answer (score 4):

We can easily see that for $x=1$ : $1-1^2 = \ln(1) \Leftrightarrow 0=0$, thus the equation is satisfied.

Let's prove that this solution is the only one as well !

$$1-x^2 = \ln(x) \Leftrightarrow \ln(x)+x^2-1 =0$$

Let $g(x) = \ln(x) + x^2 - 1$. Then, the derivative of $g(x)$, will be :

$$g'(x) = \frac{1}{x}+2x$$

Note that $g(x)$ is well defined on $\mathbb R^+ = (0,+\infty)$, which means that for our function, it's $x>0$.

For $x>0$, $g'(x) > 0 $. This means that the function $g(x)$ is strictly increasing at its domain.

Thus, if there is a $x_0 \in D_g : g(x_0)=0$, it will be the only one as well, since the function is strictly increasing.

This means that $x=1$ is the only solution.

**Note :** This is the only "entry level" way to work around such problems, that are easy to be handled like this.

In general, such problems that cannot be solved in a standard way, need numerical methods, which are methods that via repeating, converge to the solution of the equation given (there are many different methods with better convergence and different characteristics that serve different kind of problems).

Comment: What about $x^2-1 = \ln x$?

Comment: @klirk: this will have another root between 0 and 1

Comment: @Vasya I am aware of that. I was wondering how to adapt this argument in this case (OP was also asking fo it)

Comment: @klirk Let's see ! Letting $h(x) = \ln(x) - x^2 + 1$, then we'll get $h'(x) = \frac{1}{x} - 2x$. Observe that the domain of $h$, $D_h$ is again : $D_h = \mathbb R^+$. This time, though, we cannot make a statement that $h$ is strictly increasing (or decreasing) to grasp on a unique solution way, so we'll have to work around monotony, via the common way. Check where monotony changes again, check the sign change of $h(x)$,  and then via *Bolzano's Theorem*, $h$ would have a root in such a sub-domain. The root could be unique, if $h$ is strictly monotonic in that sub--domain !